# How to alter the html in the react-calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-calendar

I am designing a calendar modal, for which I have used the react-calendar npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar), I am able to alter the CSS of the package by overwriting the calendar.css in the dist folder with a local copy, but I don't understand how can I alter the HTML of the package, I have to add a text on the very top and remove few navigational buttons from the navigation panel. Please refer to the pic below, for reference.
[1st pic: what I have done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzapz.png)

[2nd pic: what I want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEZeq.png)

Comment: You might want to add some of your code. Tell people what documentation you are using and what you have tried so far to achieve your goal.

Comment: The code is of 2 lines the import statement, and the <Calendar/> declaration, there is no point in writing that, and I gave the npm package name, so far I have been following that documentation, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar) their are few props mentioned amongst which use `navigationLabel` as show below;

```
<Calendar
 onChange={this.smallCalenderChange}
 value={this.state.date}
 navigationLabel={() => <p>Choose Date</p>}
/>
```

the navigationLabel props takes a component as an argument where you can specify the header for the calendar, in my case I have given the following:-
`() => <p>Choose Date</p>`

Comment: No, it did not work, it replaced the month (Jul) with choose date whereas I want to add choose date on top of the navigation bar